# Disable comment generation in public class method snippet

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Right now VScode automatically inserts a comment before the public class method, which is kind of annoying since I often don't need the comment right away (I'd better use JSDoc snippets to have a nice documentation generated later).

[image: Example]

How can I disable this behavior?

Comment: I think this behavior comes from a VSCode plugin you have installed and activated.

Comment: @MaKobi I remember this snippet when I was first started using VSCode. I think it belongs to some kind of default snippet sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The public method completion is a snippet. If you do not wish to use the snippets, simply set:

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "none"
```

You can also [create your own snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) to customize the text that is inserted

Comment: I know about these options, I was hoping that there's some way to just remove comments for those two snippets. Anyway, thanks for an answer